# Updating LDAP directory from web application

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, spring-security, ldap, data-entry

The username/password for our web application is stored in LDAP. Right now, we have manually configured some usernames/passwords.

When a public user clicks on the 'sign up' page and signs up to our application, can we automatically update his username and password to LDAP directory? (instead of manually configuring it. Currently we store the username/password in a RDMS)

We are using JEE6 +JSF2 for web application,Spring security for Authentication and Apache Directory Studio for configuring LDAP.

Comment: Have you tried creating an LDAP entry for the user programmatically using, say, Spring LDAP?

Comment: Nope. So we can create LDAP entries programmatically using Spring LDAP ?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/

http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/basic.html#basic-binding-data

Try just insert a ldap record on sign up, and after success insert, bind on newly created user.